# Associative Array Internet Explorer 8/9

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I've an javascript Array:

```
obj[name][uid] = 10
obj[name][blub] = 12
```

When I am checking in modern browsers for

```
if(obj[name] == undefined){
...do stuff
} else ...
```

it works great.

But in IE 8 and 9 it doesnt work. How can I check in IE 8/9 if this array has been created?

Thanks, Falk

Comment: Please define "doesnt work". What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead? Also it would be nice to know the values of `name`, `uid` and `blub` variables, and how and where you've defined those variables.

Comment: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and __clear__." Really???

Comment: I don not understand what you mean Teemu. For me its clear that I had to follow the answer of Jivings.

Comment: The code you've posted works exactly in the same way in old IEs as in modern browsers. "doesn't work" is not a problem description. Please re-read my first comment.

Comment: Ok, yes you're right. The problem which occured has been at another place, but the advice I gave a thumbs up helped me to rethink my design and to work with. 
What I can say is: if i console.log obj[name] in older ie it gives me an empty array, in newer browsers it gave me a correct array. So I could not work with obj[name].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the bug in IE you're describing, but making your type checks explicit would be a good start:

```
if (typeof obj[name] === 'undefined') {
  // do stuff
}
```

The `typeof` operator is guaranteed to return a string representing the object type, whereas your type check is potentially ambiguous.